# Delete a line based on access value

Tags: c#

This program search all the facilitynumber and selects a sentence by this numbers. If he finds the number: "863790" then he selects a sentence. If he does that, he must delete this facilitynumber. This is the code I already have

```
                string[] lines = RichFacilityText.Lines;
               
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
                {
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    string query1 = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SolozinnenTabel WHERE Faciliteitnummer= " + lines[i] + " AND Paragraaf LIKE '" + AlineaDesignNaam + "%' ORDER BY rnd(ID)";
                    command.CommandText = query1;
                    OleDbDataReader reader1 = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader1.Read()) { RichAccoText.Text = RichAccoText.Text + reader1["Zin"].ToString() + ". ";
                    RichFacilityText.Lines = RichFacilityText.Lines.Where(lines => !lines[i]);
                }
```

But it doesn't work because I get the following errors

> a local variable named lines cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'lines', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.
>
> Operator "!" cannot be applied to operand of type 'char'

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? You get any exception or error message? Did you debug your code and check all values are correct?

Comment: `!lines[i]` Are you talking about a compilation error? Looks like it to me. But please clarify what "doesn't work" mean. Also clarify, is it supposed to delete from the database or just the in memory collection?

Comment: He finds the value in the access database, but the delete function doesn't work, because the error said:
a local variable named lines cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'lines', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.
Operator "!" cannot be applied to operand of type 'char'

Comment: It is supposed to delete the data in the textbox and not in the database.

Comment: Have you tried searching for any of those errors? its quite clear where you have used the word "lines" for different purposes

Comment: yeah that works, I found my mistake. But he gives me also the error:
Operator "!" cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'.

Comment: .Where(lines => !lines[i]) ... that has to be a predicate means a function that takes, in your case, a string and returns a bool... try: .Where(line=> line != lines[i])... you might also need to add a .ToArray() at the end of your assignment

Answer (score 0):

In this line `RichFacilityText.Lines.Where(lines => !lines[i])` you have a lambda expression that creates a new local variable with the name *lines*. That variable name is already used in the outer scope and was defined here: `string[] lines = RichFacilityText.Lines;` That is the reason you get the first error. Just rename one of the two variables and the error should be gone.

The second error is also because of the lambda expression `lines => !lines[i]`. The variable *lines* is a string and `lines[i]` will be evaluated to a *char*. The !-operator is not defined for the data type char, hence the error.